# WebView displaying issue

Tags: swift, uiwebview

Here is my code to display my `webView` :

```
public func displayWebView() {
    // Javascript functions implementation
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: jsFunc.close.rawValue)
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: jsFunc.setTitle.rawValue)
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: jsFunc.setBackState.rawValue)
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: jsFunc.openAlert.rawValue)
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: jsFunc.openDialog.rawValue)

    let webFrame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize.init(width: wkContainerView.frame.width, height: wkContainerView.frame.height))
    wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: webFrame , configuration: config)

    wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    wkContainerView.addSubview(wkWebView)
    wkWebView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wkContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    wkWebView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wkContainerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    wkWebView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wkContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    wkWebView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wkContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    wkWebView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wkContainerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    wkWebView.uiDelegate = self
    wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    wkWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
}
```

But the `webView` does not appear and this is what the console printed me out :

> (lldb) po webFrame ▿ (0.0, 4.94065645841247e-324,
>   2.14349191133402e-314, 3.62301730942989e-314)   ▿ origin : (0.0, 4.94065645841247e-324)
>       - x : 0.0
>       - y : 4.94065645841247e-324   ▿ size : (2.14349191133402e-314, 3.62301730942989e-314)
>       - width : 2.14349191133402e-314
>       - height : 3.62301730942989e-314

Any idea to correctly display my `webView`?

Comment: As per your console output, First check size of your wkContainerView. And make sure all constraints are set up properly. Put debug point and try to find out issue.

Comment: Constraints are set properly.

Comment: Then, Check size of wkContainerView.

Comment: Size is already set.

Comment: Can you share your project, if it is demo ?

Comment: I can't share the project, this is not a demo